# Matrix of a linear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

If I have the matrix of a linear form on the vector space $V$ which has dimension $n$, the matrix has size $n \times n$, right? Because the matrix of linear form is the matrix with the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A linear form on $V$ is a linear map from $V$ into the field $k$ that you are working with. Since $\dim V=n$ and $\dim k=1$, the matrix has $n$ columns but only $1$ row.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that i need to get a scalar as a solution. I just confused it with linear transform matrix. Thank you.